# Usando o NLog com o PostgreSQL C#

Tags: c#, postgresql, datatable, log, log4net

Eu estou trabalhando em um aplicativo, e tem algumas telas de registro, e eu quero adicionar uma rotina de log na API desses registros, digite: não adicionar, atualização e ocorrências de erro (se houver).

O banco de dados que está sendo utilizado é o PostgreSQL e aí vem o problema, eu já pesquisei vários blogs sobre como usar Log4net ou NLog e salvar os logs no banco de dados PostgreSQL, mas não achei, já fiz a lib dos dois frameworks para SqlServer e ele funciona, mas quando eu mudo para a configuração do PostgreSQL não funciona.

Alguém configurou o Log4Net ou o NLog para gravar logs no banco de dados PostGre?

Aqui estão os arquivos de como estou fazendo:

> NLog.config

```
<targets>
<target name="database" xsi:type="Database">
  <dbProvider>
    Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection,Npgsql,Version=1.22.2,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7
  </dbProvider>
  <connectionString>
    Server=SERVER;Port=0000;User Id=user;Password=pass;Database=bd;
  </connectionString>
  <commandText>
    insert into logs_nlog(level, callsite, type, message, stacktrace, innerexception, additionalinfo, loggedondate) values (@level, @callSite, @type, @message, @stackTrace, @innerException, @additionalInfo);
  </commandText>
  <parameter name="@level" layout="${level}" />
  <parameter name="@callSite" layout="Chamada: ${callsite} Linha: ${callsite-linenumber}" />
  <parameter name="@type" layout="${exception:format=type}" />
  <parameter name="@message" layout="${exception:format=message}" />
  <parameter name="@stackTrace" layout="${exception:format=stackTrace}" />
  <parameter name="@innerException" layout="${exception:format=:innerFormat=ShortType,Message,Method:MaxInnerExceptionLevel=1:InnerExceptionSeparator=}" />
  <parameter name="@additionalInfo" layout="${message}" />
</target>
```

> Na classe Client

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Log Log = new Log();
    try
    {
        Log.Info("Starting");
        int zero = 0;

        Log.Debug("Trying");
        int result = 5 / 0;
    }
    catch (DivideByZeroException ex)
    {                
        Log.Error("OMG!", ex);
    }


    Console.WriteLine("something wrong");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Há alguma mensagem de erro? Se sim, pode informar para poder te ajudar!